# How to select data to another table and update it to other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data `userid` and `votes` from table `polls` and then update `users` **table**, but can't figure out how I can do it.

When I implode ids, i got userid's like

```
293,934
```

But I dont know who I can get all userid's and their votes from table and update users table....

```
$pollid = 0 + $_GET["pollid"];
$poll_res = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM polls WHERE pollid = $pollid");

$idss = array();
        
   while($poll_row = mysql_fetch_array($poll_res)) {
        
      $idss[] = 0 + $poll_row['userid'];
   }
           
  $implode = implode(',', $idss);
  $get_votes = mysql_query("SELECT votes FROM polls WHERE pollid = $pollid AND userid In($implode)");

 // How I can update multilple user (rows) who are voted (found user votes and id from POLLS table) ?
 // I just add $votes and $userid here so you know what I want to do....

 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET total_votes = votes + $votes WHERE id = $userid");
```

Comment: first mysql_query is deprecated and you should have gotten an error second you are **vulnerable** to **sql injection** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @nbk what sql vulnerable there is?

Comment: Please read the link provided in the commnt, don't concatenate variables

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is deprected several version before the actual 8.1, if you have some old php version, you should urgently update it, use then newer mysqli or [pdo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared)

To the sql injection problem everything is explained in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and also the homepage gives you some hints https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Lets assume you have following database

```
CREATE TABLE polls(userid int,pollid INT, votes int);
INSERT INTO polls VALUES(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,0),(1,2,0),(2,2,0),(3,2,1);

CREATE tABLe users(id int, total_votes int);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,0);
```

then you would run only one query

```
<?php
$poll = 1;
/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users
JOIN ( SELECT userid ,votes FROM polls WHERE pollid = ?) t1
ON t1.userid = users.id  SET users.total_votes = users.total_votes + t1.votes");

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $poll);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* fetch value */
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

This returns.

```
2 Row inserted.
```

There are only 2 because user id 3 doesn't change the total_votes as it adds only 0 to the current value